# why i can only ping 1001 interface out of 1023 that are connected to a linux bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have create a linux bridge `br0` and create a 1023 `veth` pair such that one end is attached to bridge and other end connected to a `netns` with a IP. Now i try to ping all interface that are connect to `br0`, but i can only ping 1001 interfaces. STP is off in `br0` and IP addr of `br0` is `172.17.0.1`.

```
number=1
total_veth=1023
a=2
b=0
while [ $number -le $total_veth ]
do
  name="test${number}"
  if [ $a -gt 255 ]
  then
    a=0
    b=$(($b + 1))
  fi
  IP=172.17.$b.$a
  ip link add dev veth_b$number type veth peer name veth_e$number
  brctl addif br0 veth_b$number
  ip link set veth_b$number up
  ip netns add test$number
  ip link set veth_e$number netns test$number
  ip netns exec test$number ifconfig veth_e$number $IP/16 up 
  ip netns exec test$number route add default gw 172.17.0.1 veth_e$number
  a=$((a+1))
  echo "$number:$IP"
  number=$(($number+1))
done
```

When i remove 22 interface from bridge i can ping all 1001 interfaces. It shows there is kind limit in bridge, can someone help me to understand what is happening here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the ingress queue size by `echo 'net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 1024' >> /etc/sysctl.conf` is solved the issue, as the kernel default ingress queue size is 1000 and that's why i can only reach 1001 containers not all.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the BR_MAX_PORTS limit. Just create a second bridge and bridge the two bridges together. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496080/how-many-virtual-interfaces-can-be-added-to-default-lxcbr0-bridge-provided-by-lx) for more details.

Comment: BR_MAX_PORTS is 1024 which i haven't crossed and all interface is successfully connected to bridge ....when i invoke `brctl show` it shows `br0` and all my 1023 interface. am i missing something here.